# A link to Content documents from a VF page

Tags: content, contentversion, contentdocument

I am managing my document in SF content library.
I want to include a link to some documents in a VF page BUT I don't want the link to open the document preview on the Content tab.
I would like the document to be downloaded when the link is clicked.
This will only be available from within the organization (not a public VF page).
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: is it duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17515/how-to-get-download-link-url-from-attachment-file-in-salesforce?

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 The "Download" link that I see for a content item in a content library is `onclick="Ninja.View.isTabLink=true;Shepherd.run('document', 'downloadBegin', {id: '068i0000001ALxV', contentUrl : '', target : 'downloadIFrame', shepherdToken : 'dXDgAU4G80xvRttDcsBu3tHQUdLZAxk5LnL1pRri2VC2ewByGXKyj0W6J7slDEiGxY_pNjl0A13JI3zpfOEFWVeFRX6XQ1n7lywh.2YO6emy24Yc2PWvTgAJmlMcSNQHZCmFDgQq3D0HcCJU0LIenXi1jlA='});return false;"` so does look different to normal attachments...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can directly download using the ContentVersion Id:

```
/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/<CONTENT VERSION ID starting with 068>
```

The [ContentVersion](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) is related to the [ContentDocument](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm) via a dedicated ContentDocumentId. Get the ID of the one where `IsLatest` is true.

[image]

Comment: I would like where we can get information on /sfc/servlet.shepherd... .I have seen a lot of people using it and i have no info on that.

Comment: @unidha There are a few details in [Building Content-Rich Visualforce Pages with Salesforce CRM Content](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/04/building-content-rich-visualforce-pages-with-salesforce-crm-content.html). Mostly it seems to be a case of implying the usage from what Salesforce does with it.