# Is there a way to link to a content record from a salesforce email template?

Tags: contentversion

This is what I am working with:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Activated Agreement {!relatedTo.Name}" recipientType="User" relatedToType="ContentWorkspace">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<p>

<a href="{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140, FIND('.com/',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+4)+relatedTo.id}">{!relatedTo.Name}</a>
</p>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

> UPDATE - I tried this

```
global class RetrieveApttusContentController {

private map<String, set<String>> agreementmap = new map<String, set<String>>(); 

public static void GetContentDoc(){

    List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c> agreementList = [Select Id, Apttus__Status__c From Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c Where Apttus__Status__c =: 'Activated'];     //list of records that have been activated

    for(Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c agreementRec : agreementList){
      Set<String>ContentDocument = new Set<String>(); 
      List<ContentVersion> ConVerList = [Select contentdocumentid From ContentVersion Where IsLatest = True]; //retrieve latest version of document

      For(ContentVersion conver: ConVerList) {
        ContentDocument.add(conver.contentdocumentid);
      }
    agreementmap.put(agreementRec.id,ContentDocument);
    }
   }

    public Map<String, Set<String>>getagreementmap(){
    return agreementmap;
    }

}
```

Comment: <messaging:emailTemplate subject="Activated Agreement {!relatedTo.Name}" recipientType="User" relatedToType="ContentWorkspace">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<p>

<a href="{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_140, FIND('.com/',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_140)+4)+relatedTo.id}">{!relatedTo.Name}</a>
</p>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>

Comment: `ContentWorkspace`, your `relatedToType`, is the library where the `Content Documents` are saved (that in turn have `ContentVersion` children). See also: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36982/a-link-to-content-documents-from-a-vf-page?rq=1

Comment: So how would you build the URL?

Comment: More info is required:  (1) what triggers this email - apex, workflow, process builder?  (2) are the recipients always users in your org?

Comment: It will be triggered by a process based on a status picklist value of a custom object. The recipients are users.

Comment: sfdev09 - rather than drip feeding out bits of relevant info, may I suggest you edit your question and provide (1) a screen shot of your Process Builder flow where the email alert is kicked off from the Custom Object and, (2) most importantly, how does the process's custom object record know which ContentVersion id to provide in the email.

Comment: I am struggling to see how to fetch the recordid of where the content is the child of.  I understand the relationship b/w contentdocument and content version, but where is the hook to get the id of the record for the object?

Comment: Everything triggers off the record id of the object.  My plan was to have a process grab the latest content and then email out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "hook" is that the currentversion object creates an identifier field back to obj record id automatically when the content has been generated -- did not know and feel really stupid now.  Moving on, I was able to pass the contentdocid back to the vf template and whala it worked.  To reduce apex, I went the process and flow option and created a new field to store the contentdocid where process updates the record with the id and calls the flow which sends the email that has my contentdocid var.

Comment: glad you solved this

Answer (score 0):

The general answer to this (that I can elaborate on later) is to make the VF email template use a `relatedToType="customObj"` and then pass relatedToId as a paramter to a custom component that has its own controller.

This custom controller will fetch the custom object, traverse the related list to ContentDocument, decide which ContentDocument to use, then traverse the related list to ContentVersion to get the latest record. This ContentVersion's id is the one to use in the URL to download the record

Comment: Thanks for the direction.  I am not sure how to write the controller but this is what I think you are saying:

Comment: When I try to add the code in the comment it says its too long.

Comment: I had to post as an answer.

Comment: sfdev09 - I took the liberty to post your answer back into the question as I guessed this is work-in-progress - if not, and your answer worked for you, then great. Otherwise, the moderators can delete your answer. If it is WIP, then also post the revised VF email template and corresponding component if you followed my suggested solution

Comment: Correct, this is WIP.  I am not able to get the controller to compile.  I am still learning apex so was hoping for a little help.

Comment: sfdev09 -- just posting code without indicating where you have an error suggests we can read your mind :-)   If you want to get the full force of the community to help, you got to help us a bit more. see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Error is with line: agreementmap.put(agreementRec.id,ContentDocument);

Comment: Variable does not exist.  The reason is there is no connection between the two queries.  Again, it gets back to what is the "hook" to relate a child content document back to its parent (eg. account, opportunity).  Attachments are easy as there is related identifier back to its parent, hence the parentid.  Why content has to be so complex?