# create attachment in apex to store encoded signature

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment, images

currently i'm displaying encoded signature in my apex page in this way :

```
<apex:image value="data:image;base64,{!Call.Signature__c}" />
```

Now i want this encoded signature to be saved in attachment object and then reference it in the visualforce page for a successful renderas pdf. please provide me detail technical solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving data as an attachment is basically as simple as:

```
Attachment record = new Attachment(ParentId = call.Id, Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(call.Signature__c), ContentType = 'image/jpeg');
insert record;
```

Note that you need to know the data type of the file more than just "image", so you'll probably want to store that in a separate field.

Once saved, you can use [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17515/how-to-get-download-link-url-from-attachment-file-in-salesforce) to generate the appropriate URL for viewing/downloading/including the image.

Comment: but the problem is there are some text field values too, like {!Call.Account__c} which i also need to store inside the attachment along with the encoded signature, socan you give me details how to incorporate those texts inside that attachment body?