# What is the difference between these 2 download URLs?

Tags: formula, files

I have seen that developers use 2 different formulas for the users to download a file/attachment.

1st -

```
HYPERLINK("servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + recordId , 
          Name + "<valid extension>","_blank")`
```

2nd -

```
HYPERLINK("sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/" + recordId +
         "?asPdf=false&operationContext=CHATTER", 
         Name + "<valid extension>","_blank")
```

Can someone please explain when to use which formula?
Which recordID we are exactly passing on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former ("servlet.FileDownload") is used for classic [Attachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm) and [Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_document.htm) records, while the latter is for [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) records (e.g. as uploaded to Chatter or Salesforce Files). You use the first one to link to a file in classic storage, and the second to link to the newer file storage. In the first link, the record ID is the Document/Attachment's ID, and in the second, it's the ContentVersion ID.

Comment: Thanks Brian, so the URL parameter `operationContext` is `CHATTER` all the time for Salesforce files ?

Comment: @Bennie I don't think it's necessary; someone most likely copied a literal URL from chatter and used it in the formula. You can experiment with it to see.